In power automate, Compare two SharePoint lists for specific data, find the difference and send an email
How to compare lists in power automate and get the emails of the ones not present in one list
im trying to automate a checkin app to email a user when they aren’t signed in, and aren’t on the leave tracking SharePoint list. So I have to compare the checkin list and leave list, see who is not checked in, and then compare those that aren’t checked in to see if they are on the leave list. If they are not checked in, and not on the leave list, I want to retrieve their email and send them an email reminding them to check in. So far I get the correct people, but it sends them hundreds of emails, so obviously something in my loop structure is wrong

what does your flow look like?

I’ve tried many iterations. Current one is selecting the data from each and, filter array, then apply to each loop with filter output to send an email. Recurrence—-get items check in —-select check in —-get items leave—-select leave——filter array——for each( get user profile and send email)

refer to this when asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Ah, thank you, appreciate it

Without looping, this is a nice way … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76813346/compare-parse-json-to-sharepoint-list-with-power-automate/76816873#76816873

That’s great thank you. If I don’t have premium, would my best option be to loop through the lists, filter by name and append a variable with the filter output?
